# Openxml reading images in excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm reading the excel document using shared string and i want to check if the certain cell contains an image or not. If it does then i'll replace that image with text and save it in string.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(excelFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fs, false))
                        {
                            WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
                            SharedStringTablePart sstpart = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
                            SharedStringTable sst = sstpart.SharedStringTable;
                            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.Last();

                            Worksheet sheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

                            var cells = sheet.Descendants<Cell>();
                            var rows = sheet.Descendants<

                            // One way: go through each cell in the sheet
                            foreach (Cell cell in cells)
                            {
                                if ((cell.DataType != null) && (cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))
                                {
                                    int ssid = int.Parse(cell.CellValue.Text);
                                    string str = sst.ChildElements[ssid].InnerText;

                                    excelcontent += str+"<br>";
                                    if (cell.CellValue ==  worksheetPart.DrawingsPart.GetPartsOfType<ImagePart>())
                                    {
                                        excelcontent += textval += "<a href='../images/" + FileNameWithoutExtention + "-" + imagecount + ".jpg'><br><img src ='../images/" + FileNameWithoutExtention + "-" + imagecount + ".jpg' alt = '" + title + "-" + Image_naming + "'></a><br>";
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (cell.CellValue != null)
                                {
                                    excelcontent += textval += "<a href='../images/" + FileNameWithoutExtention + "-" + imagecount + ".jpg'><br><img src ='../images/" + FileNameWithoutExtention + "-" + imagecount + ".jpg' alt = '" + title + "-" + Image_naming + "'></a><br>";
                                    excelcontent += cell.CellValue.Text + "<br>";
                                }
                            }
```

But it is not identifying image in the cell. What should i do?

Comment: i'm using shared string table to read data

Comment: I want to store the image as a tag while reading text from excel